# Click to deploy Drupal not working

Tags: drupal, deployment, drupal-7, web-deployment, google-compute-engine

I signed up for the free trial of google cloud with the intentions of trying it out for a new drupal site I am launching. After signing up, I selected "click to deploy" the attempted to deploy drupal. When I clicked the button, nothing happens.

I tried using chrome and ie, no luck. I was successfully able to deploy a WP site so I am not sure why drupal is not working. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: As an alternative, you can also [launch Drupal on GCP via Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/drupal/cloud/google).

Answer (score 2):

Automatic installation of Drupal and its hosting in the cloud is also available within Jelastic PaaS. You can follow the [guide with simple steps](https://jelastic.com/blog/how-to-install-drupal-cms-to-the-cloud/) to get it up and running in a few clicks. Here you'll have automatic scaling, pay-per-use pricing, management via intuitive UI, a wide choice of local service providers from different countries and other options.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a general issue deploying Drupal on GCE. Google is already working on this issue as per [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=183).